# Invoking ffmpeg through bash through command prompt

Tags: windows, bash, shell, ffmpeg

I have a ffmpeg command which I am trying to run in python.  Invoking it in wsl or bash works fine.

The command:

`ffmpeg -y -i C:/Users/joel/src/tldr-dw/src/test/video_editor/input.mp4 -lavfi '[0:v]scale=ih*16/9:-1,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=h=iw*9/16,scale=1920x1080' -vb 5m C:/Users/joel/src/tldr-dw/src/test/video_editor/input_output.mp4`

However, I am trying to get this to run in python.  I am invoking it like so:

`subprocess.check_output([r'C:\Windows\SysNative\bash.exe', '-c', bash_command], shell=True)`

but am getting an error message:

`C:/Users/joel/src/tldr-dw/src/test/video_editor/input.mp4: Protocol not found Did you mean file:C:/Users/joel/src/tldr-dw/src/test/video_editor/input.mp4?`

I've tried appending "file" to the input/output paths and even switching to windows line endings.  When I do the latter, it seems to escape the slashes.  I get this error message:

`C:Usersjoelsrctldr-dwsrctestvideo_editorinput.mp4: Protocol not found Did you mean file:C:Usersjoelsrctldr-dwsrctestvideo_editorinput.mp4?`

All I am trying to do is run a bash command in ffmpeg from the command prompt, essentially.  I get similar error messages on there.  What is going on with the file paths?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I need to use a POSIX-style path starting with /mnt/...so like

```
/mnt/c/Users/joel/src/tldr-dw/temp/input.mp4
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: It would be awesome that you can edit the title of your question to specify that you were working with Windows and not linux. I know that there is a part in your question that already says that you are working with WSL but to have it in the title will help more. It worked for me, thanks for your question and answer.